# Display the icon on the upper left on the td

Tags: css, html

Goal:
Display the icon on the upper left of the selected td when you have the cursor over the td.

Problem:
I have tried to find different solution but it doesn't go so well.

Thank you!

```css
table.glyphicon-hover .glyphicon {
  visibility: hidden;
}

table.glyphicon-hover td:hover .glyphicon {
  visibility: visible;
      position:relative;
    background-color: green;

}

.test {
  text-align:right;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
  
  <body>

<div class="container">

  
  <table class="test table table-striped glyphicon-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>kkjkjkjkjsfdsdfg</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-trash-a-20.png"></span>
        <span>sfsdf!</span> <br>sdfsdf <br>sdfsdf <br> sdfsdf
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      sdsdfsdf sf <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `td` to have relative positioning and the icon to have absolute positioning. Then you can position it using `left` and `top`.

```css
table.glyphicon-hover .glyphicon {
  visibility: hidden;
  position:absolute;
}

table.glyphicon-hover td:hover .glyphicon {
visibility: visible;
background-color: green;
left: 0;
}

.table td {
position: relative
}

.test {
  text-align:right;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
  
  <body>

<div class="container">

  
  <table class="test table table-striped glyphicon-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>kkjkjkjkjsfdsdfg</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-trash-a-20.png"></span>
        <span>sfsdf!</span> <br>sdfsdf <br>sdfsdf <br> sdfsdf
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      sdsdfsdf sf <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See the below code

new class added `.topleftIcon`

All I'm doing is floating the icon to the left.

```css
table.glyphicon-hover .glyphicon {
  visibility: hidden;
}

table.glyphicon-hover td:hover .glyphicon {
  visibility: visible;
      position:relative;
    background-color: green;

}

.test {
  text-align:right;  
}

.topleftIcon{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
  
  <body>

<div class="container">

  
  <table class="test table table-striped glyphicon-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>kkjkjkjkjsfdsdfg</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up topleftIcon"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-trash-a-20.png"></span>
        <span>sfsdf!</span> <br>sdfsdf <br>sdfsdf <br> sdfsdf
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      sdsdfsdf sf <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up topleftIcon"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!